# AirPlay Mirroring iPhone to Mac OS / using UIWebView + AirPlay

Tags: ios, ios5, airplay

I need to live-demo a Mobile Safari browser app (iOS 5, iPhone 4S) on my Macbook and was wondering the best way to do this?

One way I thought might be possible would be using AirPlay Mirroring, but there doesn't seem to be any Mac OS apps capable of showing my iPhone screen mirrored.

I am an (beginner) iOS developer and wondered if there was anyway I could knock up a basic app with a UIWebView in it to somehow stream the contents of the web page and my interactions with it to my Mac.

Any thoughts?

*EDIT*: Yes I know I could use the iPhone Simulator, but I need to interact with it on the handset using the mobile phone network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation has changed since this was asked.

AirServer (AirServerApp.com) and Reflection (ReflectionApp.com) both support AirPlay mirroring. Here's an article comparing them:

http://www.macstories.net/reviews/mirroring-multiple-ios-devices-to-a-mac-comparing-airserver-and-reflection/

Answer (score 1):

Since your device (iPhone 4s) supports video mirroring via AirPlay, then you should be able to use [AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com/) to enable mirroring to your Mac.

Update: As pointed out by Marc Surman, AirServer does not support mirroring, rendering this answer incorrect.  Thanks for playing.

Comment: AirServer does not support video mirroring. It's on the front page of the website.

Answer (score 0):

Mirroring uses FairPlay encryption, which is why AirServer and similar applications can't do mirroring.

You CAN, however, fake this using AirplayKit:
https://github.com/rothacr/AirplayKit

The iOS demo in that repo actually does a simple mirror by sending an image of your screen to the airplay device using a timer. It would probably work just fine for a demo, and should work with AirServer.